# How to check if a binary file contains some expected data?

Tags: c

I am creating a small database, whose data is contained in a binary file. At this moment, the program only reads data in the file or overwrites that data. The database is represented by a struct `Database`. The problem is that if I read right way the file without checking whether data exist, the program stops working. This is how it prints data:

```
        printf("nth of table: %d\n", table->id);
        printf("table name: %s\n", table->name);
```

I guess because there is not data in id and name, so that the program stops working. If I initialize the data in the struct database, this would not happen, but it is only ok if I want to overwrite the database.

So is there any way to check if the data read from the binary file is what I expect like table->id = "something"?

Or what is the other way to read data from file to a struct like the database and make sure that there is no such problem?

The below is relevant code of my program.

```
        struct Database {
            int num_table;
            char *name;
            struct Table *table_list[MAX_TABLE]; // contains pointers to each table in the database


        };


        struct Table {
            int id; 
            int num_row;
            char *name;
            struct Row *row[MAX_ROW]; // pointer to each row in a table

        };

    struct Connection{
        FILE *file;
        struct Database *db;

    };

void load_db(struct Connection *conn){
    int result = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(!result)
        //printf("result%d", result);
        die("cannot load database");
}

        struct Connection *connect_db (char *file_name, char *mode){
            // allocate memory
            struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
            if(!conn)
                die("memory error with connection");
            conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
            if(!(conn->db))
                die("memory error with database");

            // open stream and load database from the file
            if(strcmp(mode, "w") == 0){
                conn->file = fopen(file_name, mode);
                //load_db(conn); // load data from file
            }else if(strcmp(mode, "r") == 0){
                conn->file = fopen (file_name, mode);
                load_db(conn); // load data from file
            }else{
                die("incorrect mode");

            }

            return conn;

        }


        int print_record(char *table_name, struct Database *db){

            struct Table **table_list = db->table_list;
            struct Table *table;
            int all_num_table = db->all_num_table; // include those deleted
            int i = 0;



            if(strcmp(table_name, "all") == 0){ // assume users enter 'all' not 'All' or so on

                for (i; i < all_num_table; i++){
                    table = table_list[i];

                    if((table->id != -1) && ()){
                        printf("nth of table: %d\n", table->id);
                        printf("table name: %s\n", table->name);
                        printf("Number of rows: %d\n", table->num_row);
                        printf("Number of available rows: %d\n", (MAX_ROW - (table->num_row)));

                        printf("-----------------------------");

                        // record of each row is in here

                        printf("--------- End of table nth: %d ----------\n", table->id);
                    }

                }

            }else{


            }

        }
```

Comment: Don't use binary files. Read about Serialization. Consider using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but where do you actually read from `conn->file`?

Comment: @Mr. Llama, i declare conn in the first line of function connect_db. Because file is member of struct Connection, and conn->file is valid

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I find your advice confusing, since I think he should be using serialization to access binary files.  Maybe you meant don't read/write structs directly from a binary file using fread/fwrite?

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch, thanks for the advice, I just do this for learning C.

Comment: @PMH - I get that you declare `conn->file` and that's good, but please include your `load_db` function.  **That's** where you should be checking if the data loaded correctly.

Comment: @Mr. Llama. I just included the load function.

Comment: You'll need e.g. a header which indicates the content of your db file (for instance, the number of records). This way you are guaranteed to be able to read at least these bytes successfully. Have a look at e.g. the BMP format: it's well documented and illustrates the general technique.

Comment: If you need to test if your data is *exactly* what you expect it to be -- literally -- then you don't have to read it... If you are worried about data integrity, add a checksum. If you are worried about synchronization, add fixed identifiers between your data items; possibly also a data length field. Look at the PNG and IFF file formats for hints.

Answer (score 0):

What your problem is: you're reading a complex data structure that contains pointers directly from a file as binary data.

That approach has several drawbacks:

- If the data structure contains pointers, it will only read the values of the pointers, not the data the pointers point to
- If you write the data on one machine and access it on a different machine, the representations can differ (e.g. due to differences between 32-bit and 64-bit machines)

Don't do that. You should really read about serialization. I.e. if you want to serialize a char* string, you could first write the length of the string using 4 bytes in network byte order, and then write the individual bytes of the string. When you read the data, you read the string length, allocate memory using malloc() and read the individual bytes.

Unfortunately you will need WAY more lines of code than what your example program shows. E.g. I recently wrote data serialization and unserialization routines for a reasonably simple data structure (albeit more complex than yours) and they are 1000 lines of code.

If you don't understand why the data structure raw read/write doesn't work, you should perhaps be using a different language than C at this point of time. C is for experts.